# Pandas .dt.round rounds the nearest hour randomly?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a variable with 3 timestamps.

```
a = DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-26 20:30:00', '2016-01-26 21:30:00','2016-01-26 22:30:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H')
```

**I've now since learned that the round function rounds according to these rules "when halfway between two integers the even integer is chosen."**

```
a.round('H')
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-26 20:00:00', '2016-01-26 22:00:00','2016-01-26 22:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

How I can make sure it rounds all 30 minute timestamps (e.g. 20:30, 19:30) to the next hour.

Thanks!

Edit:

I have tried the following function from [Pandas Timestamp rounds 30 seconds inconsistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56633395/pandas-timestamp-rounds-30-seconds-inconsistently)

```
def half_up_minute(x):
    m = (x - x.floor('H')).total_seconds() < 30   # Round True Down, False Up
    return x.where(m).floor('H').fillna(x.ceil('H'))
```

but get the following error:

`TypeError: 'value' must be a scalar, passed: DatetimeIndex`

Comment: Answer is about `30S`, but I think it is same problem like here.

Comment: That function does not work for me. I get an error:
```AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt```

When I remove the ```.dt``` I get the following error:
```TypeError: 'value' must be a scalar, passed: DatetimeIndex```

Comment: Only remove `.dt`

Comment: OK, I am going to test it. Expected output is `21,22,23` ?

Comment: @jezrael yes, it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change function for replace `fillna` Series to second argument in [`Index.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.where.html) and compare by `30 Minutes`:

```
def half_up_minute(x):
    m = (x - x.floor('H')).total_seconds() < 30 * 60   
    return x.floor('H').where(m, x.ceil('H'))

print (half_up_minute(a))
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-26 21:00:00', '2016-01-26 22:00:00',
               '2016-01-26 23:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

---

```
a = pd.date_range('2016-01-26 20:30:00', periods=20, freq='10T')
print (a)
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-26 20:30:00', '2016-01-26 20:40:00',
               '2016-01-26 20:50:00', '2016-01-26 21:00:00',
               '2016-01-26 21:10:00', '2016-01-26 21:20:00',
               '2016-01-26 21:30:00', '2016-01-26 21:40:00',
               '2016-01-26 21:50:00', '2016-01-26 22:00:00',
               '2016-01-26 22:10:00', '2016-01-26 22:20:00',
               '2016-01-26 22:30:00', '2016-01-26 22:40:00',
               '2016-01-26 22:50:00', '2016-01-26 23:00:00',
               '2016-01-26 23:10:00', '2016-01-26 23:20:00',
               '2016-01-26 23:30:00', '2016-01-26 23:40:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='10T')

def half_up_minute(x):
    m = (x - x.floor('H')).total_seconds() < 30 * 60   
    return x.floor('H').where(m, x.ceil('H'))

print (half_up_minute(a))
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-26 21:00:00', '2016-01-26 21:00:00',
               '2016-01-26 21:00:00', '2016-01-26 21:00:00',
               '2016-01-26 21:00:00', '2016-01-26 21:00:00',
               '2016-01-26 22:00:00', '2016-01-26 22:00:00',
               '2016-01-26 22:00:00', '2016-01-26 22:00:00',
               '2016-01-26 22:00:00', '2016-01-26 22:00:00',
               '2016-01-26 23:00:00', '2016-01-26 23:00:00',
               '2016-01-26 23:00:00', '2016-01-26 23:00:00',
               '2016-01-26 23:00:00', '2016-01-26 23:00:00',
               '2016-01-27 00:00:00', '2016-01-27 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```